# Build Error - Entry 'res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png' name differ (56 vs 54)

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors

Whilst compiling a project, I got an error which I have not seen before.
**Entry 'res/drawable-xhdpi-v4/notification_bg_low_normal.9.png' name differ (56 vs 54)**

I am not using this png in my code so I am not sure why this error is occuring.
[Build Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsVqJ.png)

Comment: It would be helpful to add the error to the actual question (or at least the relevant parts), the in future this question might help others! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot.

Answer (score -2):

from top menu bar select Build that will open small menu choose **Rebuild Project** from this menu .

[image]